# JAVA: JCheckBox lost selection in a JTable when Button pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have this problem: added a **jcheckbox** in a **jtable**. In my model this jcheckbox is loaded with `getValueAt` and used the method `setValueAt` when selected by the user.

No problem until I push the confirm button, when all my row selected (true value) disappear and the loop doesn't read anything with true value.

Where is my mistake? How can I update the model before pressing my confirmation button?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for:

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateOnFocusLost", true);
```

This tells the table to try to commit any ongoing edits when the focus is transfered to the outside, that is to a component which is not a child of the table.